# Use http.TimeoutHandler or ReadTimeout/WriteTimeout?

Tags: go

Does it make sense to additionally use [http.TimeoutHandler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#TimeoutHandler) if I already set the [server's](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout? It seems as if this scenario is mutually exclusive?

Comment: These two are completely unrelated. So you may use both.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53051253/4213218

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**These two deal with different aspects of http request/response lifecycle.**

`http.TimeoutHandler` is used to limit execution time of the http.Handler. it will return `503` status code *to the client*, if `http.Handler` doesn't finish in stipulated time.

While, `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` deals with network I/O timeout, i.e time required to read/write request/response body *to your client* respectively.

So, `http.TimeoutHandler` handles the case where your handler (code block that handles http request) need to be complete in set amount of time, by wrapping your original handler. while `http.WriteTimeout` or `http.ReadTimeout` is used when you dont want to wait for network read/write of request/response indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Judging by @Zak's comment and graph, `http.TimeoutHandler` should be covered by the the `http.Server.WriteTimeout`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @mattes, No, `TimeoutHandler` handles the case where your handler (code block that handles http request) need to be complete in set amount of time, while `WriteTimeout` is used when you dont want to wait for network write indefinitely.

Comment: @desaiparth hi, I'm using `http.TimeoutHandler` and after it return status `503`, the handler (code block that handles http request) still executing. How can I terminate the execution of handler?

Comment: @Souji Tendo You should listen channel of request context <-ctx.Done(). When there timeout you will get singal by listening channel of context.

Answer (score 12):

This blog article does a good job of explaining, but essentially they fulfil slightly different roles, as demonstrated here:

[image]

[Link to blog article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/)

You've not included what your usecase is, but hopefully this is enough information to be able to make a decision.

Comment: Thanks @Zak! The use case is to limit the time a `http.Handler` can run. It seems as if I don't have to set `http.TimeoutHandler` if I set `http.Server.ReadTimeout` and `http.Server.WriteTimeout` instead. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree that setting read and write timeouts on the server is important. If the code is easy to include, I can see an argument for the added flexibility and control that you could have by using `http.TimeoutHandler` to enforce this case. But as already discussed, I think it's not strictly necessary if you have timeouts in other places. I think that the server timeouts are to defend against unresponsive clients, and the `httpTimeoutHandler` is to defend against slow handlers. In your case, I think you are worried about the slow handler?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for clearing up the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to expose your app naked (directly) no HAproxy/Nginx in front, changing the defaults may help, for example (fine-tune them based on your requirements):

```
// configure server
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        router,
    ReadTimeout:    5 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   7 * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

Here is a very nice article explaining more about the topic: https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/

Comment: Thanks. I read this blog post. I want to add that it seems important to eventually provide a custom `TCPListener` as well to override the 3 minutes default KeepAlive Timeout to something shorter. Source: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/exposing-go-on-the-internet/

Comment: If you sed `ReadTimeout` = 5s, how you can upload large file to the server? For example you need to upload 10mb image file, it takes 30s. So it would failed to serve?

Comment: @TomSawyer check this post/gist https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/NBhJqZe25EA, https://gist.github.com/jbardin/9663312 it could give you some ideas

Answer (score 1):

Here is one good sample [Diving into Go's HTTP server timeouts](https://adam-p.ca/blog/2022/01/golang-http-server-timeouts/)

- There are two cases when TimeoutHandler returns 503.

  - The first is, of course, when the deadline is set on the context fires (it could have been set somewhere else, in theory).
  - The other is if the context was canceled for some other reason (such as the client leaving). They are distinguishable from the client-side because there’s no response body in the latter case
- Configuring `ReadHeaderTimeout` would protect directly against this attack by closing the connection once the deadline is reached, to [Mitigate a Slowloris Attack](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-understand-and-mitigate-slowloris-attack-711c1b1403f6)
- `ReadTimeout` is the one we would need to configure here since it covers the header and the body of the HTTP requests, to [Mitigate R.U.D.Y attack](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-how-to-mitigate-rudy-dos-attack-3bd9c1662848)
- Let’s work through the timeout math

  - Let’s say we want, generally, a 10-second request timeout. So we set TimeoutHandler’s timeout to 10 seconds.
  - We need to pick a ReadHeaderTimeout that is basically independent from that (because the handler timeout doesn’t start until after the header read is complete). It seems reasonable to pick 5 seconds.
  - As discussed above, we prefer the ReadTimeout to be longer than the handler timeout, so the client has a chance of getting the response. Because ReadTimeout ticks away during the header read, the calculation for this is something like:

  `ReadTimeout := handler_timeout + ReadHeaderTimeout + wiggle_room`

Answer (score 0):

Also exists important difference between them if you are use Context.
In case if you are use http.TimeoutHandler, you will get cancel signal from request context <-ctx.Done() with which you can terminate running processes.

In case if you are use WriteTimeout and if given time limit is reached you will not get cancel signal from request context.