# How to implement server side timeouts? (Confused about http.Server timeouts)

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement server-side timeouts for my service. If the request takes longer than X seconds, the server should return 503 Service Unavailable.

I know that this can easily be accomplished by wrapping all of my endpoints in [http.TimeoutHandler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#TimeoutHandler), but I'm confused why this isn't being done automatically by the [Timeout fields of http.Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server)

Here is a trivial example that I am using for testing. If I cURL or POSTman this server, it hangs forever, rather than the 5 seconds I expect.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/timeouttest", func(_ http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
        // busy infinite loop
        // for { _ = struct {}{}}

        // non-busy infinite loop
        select {}
    })
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:              "localhost:5000",
        Handler:           mux,
        ReadTimeout:       5 * time.Second,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:      5 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
    }
    srv.ListenAndServe()
}
```

EDIT: forgot to link some Cloudflare articles that I have been using as inspiration. 
[complete guide to golang http timeouts](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/)
[so you want to expose go on the internet](https://blog.cloudflare.com/exposing-go-on-the-internet/)

Comment: Why exactly do you think that should timeout? The timeouts are for when the client is too slow, but you are purposely blocking the server's handler code, so none of those timeouts apply. You've already mentioned the correct answer, which is to set a timeout for the entire handler itself.

Comment: I second @JimB's answer that `http.TimeoutHandler` is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: @JimB I guess I don't fully understand what `ReadTimeout`, `ReadHeaderTimeout`, and `WriteTimeout` are for then. Is it solely to safeguard against malicious clients?

Comment: They are for precisely what their names describe; `ReadTimeout` is the timeout when reading a request, `ReadHeaderTimeout` is the timeout reading only the request headers, and `WriteTimeout` is the timeout writing a response. Your handler is not reading or writing _anything_ while it is blocked, nor can your handler actually cause those to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `http.TimeoutHandler`. I misunderstood the purpose of the `http.Server` Timeout fields.